# Custom Error page InvalidArgumentException Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to generate a custom error page in symfony2:
I was following this [tuto](http://symfonybricks.com/en/brick/custom-exception-page-404-not-found-and-other-exceptions).
However it shows me this:

```
InvalidArgumentException in YamlFileLoader.php line 145: A service definition must be an array or a string starting with "@" but NULL found for service "kernel.listener.allotaxi_exception_listener" in services.yml. Check your YAML syntax.
```

my services.yml :

```
services:
    kernel.listener.allotaxi_exception_listener:
    class: AlloTaxi\AlloTaxiBundle\Listener\ExceptionListener
    arguments: [@templating, @kernel]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
```

ExceptionListener.php :

```
namespace AlloTaxi\AlloTaxiBundle\Listener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface;
class ExceptionListener {

    protected $templating;
    protected $kernel;

    public function __construct(EngineInterface $templating, $kernel)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
        }

        public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
        {
        // provide the better way to display a enhanced error page only in prod environment, if you want
        if ('prod' == $this->kernel->getEnvironment()) {
        // exception object
        $exception = $event->getException();

        // new Response object
        $response = new Response();

        // set response content
        $response->setContent(
            // create you custom template AcmeFooBundle:Exception:exception.html.twig
            $this->templating->render(
                'AlloTaxiBundle:Exception:error.html.twig',
                array('exception' => $exception)
            )
        );

        // HttpExceptionInterface is a special type of exception
        // that holds status code and header details
        if ($exception instanceof HttpExceptionInterface) {
            $response->setStatusCode($exception->getStatusCode());
            $response->headers->replace($exception->getHeaders());
        } else {
            $response->setStatusCode(500);
        }

        // set the new $response object to the $event
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
}
```

Any idea what could it be? I followed exactly when he did there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
services:
    kernel.listener.allotaxi_exception_listener:
        class: AlloTaxi\AlloTaxiBundle\Listener\ExceptionListener
        arguments: [@templating, @kernel]
        tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
```

By looking at the services.yml file posted in your question, you are missing the indentation level for "class", "arguments" & "tags". They appear to be at the same level as that of your service name "kernel.listener.allotaxi_exception_listener"

Have a look at above service definition, notice the indentation between service name and  class, arguments & tags.

When dealing with yml files one needs to be careful about proper hierarchy